Why does Heep refer to Copperfield sometimes as mister and sometimes as master?
In Dickens' David Copperfield, the character Uriah Heep refers to David sometimes as "Mister Copperfield" and sometimes as "Master Copperfield."  Other times, he makes a point to say something like

'Oh, really, Master Copperfield,' he rejoined—'I beg your pardon, Mister Copperfield'... (emphasis mine)

As can be expected with Dickens, Heep works this mister/master business into almost every chapter he appears in.  What is its significance?  Please, are you able to explain without any massive spoilers to someone only two-thirds of the way through?  So assume in answering that I have a good general impression of Heep's character but don't know anything that may occur after Chapter 40 or so.

"Master" was a term then often used for young boys in British society (still present today, but to a lesser degree). "Mister", on the other hand, is generally used for addressing peers. So basically, Heep is both making a snide insult against David by using a term for children, and also making reference to having known David since childhood.
The Schmoop study guide specifically mentions it being used in that context.

One last note on Uriah Heep: once Uriah meets up with David once more in London, when David is an apprentice proctor, you'll notice that he keeps confusing "Mister" and "Master" Copperfield. He claims that this confusion is accidental, because he has such affectionate memories of young Master Copperfield. Really, it's a power play: "Master" is a form of address for little boys, while Mister (obviously) is for grown men. Uriah Heep is trying to throw David off by reminding David how young he is, and that Uriah Heep has known him since he was a ragged little boy. Just another piece of psychological warfare from this master manipulator!


Not only from those who serve them: it is (or was?) a general term used for boys too young to be called Mister. I grew up being Master [al'Thor] (or sometimes, as a joke, Daster [al'Thor] because "if the son of a Mister is a Master, then the son of a Doctor is a Daster").

I wouldn't say it was 'often' used nowadays.

Good point. I indicated that it was a common trend back then.

When I travelled as a child with my parents, my plane tickets said master instead of mister (I think abbreviated, MSTR?). That was maybe only 16 years ago... maybe they still do it?
